# Manhwa or webcomic where the male main character has light blue hair and uses a rapier as main weapon and goes to an academy

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

It starts off with the main character (MC) who was found in a forbidden/monster-ridden area and a lady decides to raise him and make him her disciple. Then the story progresses and his master dies at the hands of the villagers she helped, because someone she was on bad terms with put a bounty on her.

Before her death, she promises the MC that her friends, the other strong people they once traveled with, will become his family. But they end up hating the MC and make him go to an academy that teaches swordsmanship and also has elemental powers.

Then, later on in the story, I think it’s said a friend of his actually killed his master and took her powers. Also, at the beginning of the story, I think the MC gets a new roommate and becomes friends with them. A personality trait of the MC is that he’s cold in the beginning.

Also I think it used to be on Toomics; not too sure though. I think I read it somewhere between 2020-2021.